# how to compare two lists of lists

Tags: groovy

I'm using groovy scripting in Soapui and I'm facing a comparison problem between two lists of lists:
on the one hand I have the expected value (type String), on the other I have the recovered value (type ArrayList).

expected value is like this :

```
expected [[hsb:[100, 100, 100], type:hsb, wt:null], [hsb:null, type:wt, wt:60]]
```

recovered one is like this :

```
recovered [[type:hsb, wt:null, hsb:[100, 100, 100]], [type:wt, wt:60, hsb:null]]
```

so basically it should match, however I can't figure out how to do it programmatically.

If I convert "expected" into an array, using `expected_collection = expected_value.tokenize('[]')`, I lose my elements and parsing the array gives the following :

```
Thu Nov 14 16:42:31 CET 2019: INFO: hsb:
Thu Nov 14 16:42:31 CET 2019: INFO: 100, 100, 100
Thu Nov 14 16:42:31 CET 2019: INFO: , type:hsb, wt:null
Thu Nov 14 16:42:31 CET 2019: INFO: , 
Thu Nov 14 16:42:31 CET 2019: INFO: hsb:null, type:wt, wt:60
```

Is it possible to tokenize on a limited level ? ie. only the first level of [] ?

Comment: Your main problem is that you are trying to compare a string representation of the list with a regular list. If only you could declare expected list as a `List<Map>`, then Groovy's `==` operator would compare two lists of maps, no matter in what order maps are located in those lists. (Map's `==` also does not care about keys-values order)

Comment: in soapui when you pass parameters through custom properties you end up with strings ... I'll check if I can set them as list of map before passing them through custom properties (in that case a json parseText allow to recover it in a more suitable format)

Comment: It worked actually !  :)  thanks for your help